# Upper Bound for inverse selfadjoint operator between Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am not very steady in Functional Analysis. I try to follow a certain proof and do not get the last part.
Theorem: Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A\in L(H)$ a bounded linear  and self adjoint operator. Then $$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow ||(z-A)^{-1}||_{L(H)} \leq \frac{1}{|\Im(z)|}$$
For the proof by using the self adjointness we can show that the following inequality holds:
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R} , u \in H\quad ||u||\leq \frac{1}{|\Im(z)|}||(z-A)(u)||_{L(H)}$$
How does this Inequality now implies the above theorem?
Probably the answer is easy and I am missing something. Thanks in advance

Comment: Set $u:= (z-A)^{-1}v$. (Of course, you need to show that the inverse exists in the first place)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This answers my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your inequality by putting an absolute value around $\Im(z),$ and apply it to $u=(z-A)^{-1}(v),$ for any $v\in H.$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Take any $v \in H$ and write $v=(z-A)(u)$ or $u=(z-A)^{-1} v$. We get $\|(z-A)^{-1}v\| \leq \frac 1 {\Im z } \|v\|$.

Comment: Thank you too!!